# angular 7: Cannot display the img

Tags: angular, angular7

Im doing the thing like this angular js example :
https://jsbin.com/gumaraz/edit?html,output

but i need to do with Angular 7 and i tried to upgrade the code from Angular.js to angular however it cannot display anything

component.html

```
  WidthLength : <input type="number" min="1" step="5" [(ngModel)]="widthLength" (change)="showPic()" ><br>
  HeightLength : <input type="number" min="1" step="5" [(ngModel)]="heightLength" (change)="showPic()"><br>

  <img [src]='imageUrl '/>
```

component.ts

```
  widthLength = '1024';
  heightLength = '768';
  imageUrl = 'https://lorempixel.com/{{widthLength}}/{{heightLength}}/';

  showPic() {
    if (this.widthLength !== null && this.heightLength !== null &&
      this.widthLength !== undefined && this.heightLength !== undefined) {
      this.imageUrl = 'http://lorempixel.com/' + this.widthLength + '/' + this.heightLength + '/';
    } else {
      alert('null');
    }
  }
```

my Code(stakblitz): 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-555ojr

can anyone help me please

Comment: Is not your fault. LoremPixel use http while you are using https. If you open the network tab you will see something like this: `The page at .... was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.` You can try to build your app and try to open the index.html generated to see if, in that case, works.

Comment: ok let me try tq

Comment: mate i have been updated my Q

Comment: You can try in any possible way. But if you create an index.html file in desktop with the code `<html>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" />
</html>` it will work fine. If you put the same code in an html page in the angular page it wont. That's because angular use HTTPS while the standard html page doesn't by default(it's kinda obv since it's just a stand-alone page w/0 a web server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you edited your question with actual code:

1. Remove that dummy initialization value
2. Call `showPic()` somewhere
3. Use HTTPS

   ```
     widthLength = '1024';
     heightLength = '768';
     imageUrl = null; // removed dumb initialization value.

     ngOnInit(){
        this.showPic(); // call it here for example
     }
     showPic() {
       if (this.widthLength !== null && this.heightLength !== null &&
         this.widthLength !== undefined && this.heightLength !== undefined) {
         this.imageUrl = 'https://lorempixel.com/' + this.widthLength + '/' + this.heightLength + '/';
       } else {
         alert('null');
       }  
      }
   ```

If you will still have troubles with that, prepare working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) and share editor link.

Comment: Prepare stackblitz

Answer (score 1):

Your URL is malformed. You are trying to get resource like

https://lorempixel.com/{{widthLength}}/{{heightLengt} which obviously does not exist. Prepare your URL correctly as your `widthLength` and `heightLength` does not get resolved.

I can only assume that those are component/local variables so it should be more like

imageUrl = `http://lorempixel.com/${widthLength}/${heightLength}/`;
in case of local variables, or `this.widthLength` and so on in case of component field

Comment: tq mate actually im doing the thing like this example : https://jsbin.com/gumaraz/edit?html,output
but the example is angular js and i need to play by angular so i used {{widthLength}}{{heightLength}}

here is my unfinished code : imgur.com/a/fkiYLEH anyone can give me some advice?

Comment: 1) remove that dumb imageUrl initialization value. 2) call that showPic() somewhere..... 3) stop pasting images and include actual code 4) even better, include working example on stackblitz.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (Over secured network `https`)

```
imageUrl = 'https://lorempixel.com/400/400/';
<img [src]=" imageUrl ">
```

If you want to set height and width dynamic, try to set using a variable.

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/lorem-image?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: tq mate unfortunately still cannot display and the console error shows: 
`GET https://lorempixel.com/%7B%7BwidthLength%7D%7D/%7B%7BheightLength%7D%7D/ 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: Strange, Can you paste your code on stackblitz? I am curios to check why not working on your side, either probably you write code on wrong place

Comment: @PardeepJain his URl is not interpolated.

Comment: @Antoniossss Yes, that's why mentioned in answer for dynamic height and width

Comment: Right didnt notice that .

Comment: tq mate actually im doing the thing like this example : jsbin.com/gumaraz/edit?html,output but the example is angular js and i need to play by angular so i used {{widthLength}}{{heightLength}} here is my unfinished code : imgur.com/a/fkiYLEH anyone can give me some advice?

Comment: Stop pasting images, update your question and include code there.